# Counting all words in a column of a dataset pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, columnsorting, eda

I am carrying out EDA on a dataset and want to count the total number of words in a column, before and after deleting duplicates.

Here is my code:

```py
print(train_dataset['text'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(' '))).sum())
```

It is throwing this error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset as text

Comment: The problem is that `split` is part of the `str`-functions, but there's probably a better (i.e., more "panda-esque") way of doing this. Can you share an example of what the `text`-column looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert column values to string type before split:

```
train_dataset['text'] = train_dataset['text'].astype(str)
train_dataset['text'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split())).sum()
# or
train_dataset['text'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split())).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks @Grey Murev. it worked